# React-Select: Show search bar in dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I love the implementation of [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) and am looking forward to using it in my project.

Is there a way to add a search bar (a la [react-widgets - DropdownList](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DropdownList/)) to the dropdown? In testing with our designer and users we've found that users do not always realize the dropdown is searchable and appeared to overwhelmingly prefer the DropwdownList widget due to that one feature.

That said, I love the react-select's customizability and feature set and hope to be able to use it.

-Daniel

Comment: I put in a Feature Request for this as well. You might add your own comments to help move it along...

Comment: The link to that FR https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3111

Answer (score 10):

There's an [example](https://react-select.com/advanced#experimental) which looks very similar to what you're after on the advanced section of the `react-select` docs. It requires using custom components but it's possible.

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bhabha-2mpiq?fontsize=14)

Here's the code they provide in the docs:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { Component } from 'react';
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core';
import Button from '@atlaskit/button';

import Select from 'react-select';
import { defaultTheme } from 'react-select';
import { stateOptions } from '../data';

const { colors } = defaultTheme;

const selectStyles = {
  control: provided => ({ ...provided, minWidth: 240, margin: 8 }),
  menu: () => ({ boxShadow: 'inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)' }),
};

type State = { isOpen: boolean, value: Object };

export default class PopoutExample extends Component<*, State> {
  state = { isOpen: false, value: undefined };
  toggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ isOpen: !state.isOpen }));
  };
  onSelectChange = value => {
    this.toggleOpen();
    this.setState({ value });
  };
  render() {
    const { isOpen, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <Dropdown
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClose={this.toggleOpen}
        target={
          <Button
            iconAfter={<ChevronDown />}
            onClick={this.toggleOpen}
            isSelected={isOpen}
          >
            {value ? `State: ${value.label}` : 'Select a State'}
          </Button>
        }
      >
        <Select
          autoFocus
          backspaceRemovesValue={false}
          components={{ DropdownIndicator, IndicatorSeparator: null }}
          controlShouldRenderValue={false}
          hideSelectedOptions={false}
          isClearable={false}
          menuIsOpen
          onChange={this.onSelectChange}
          options={stateOptions}
          placeholder="Search..."
          styles={selectStyles}
          tabSelectsValue={false}
          value={value}
        />
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}

// styled components

const Menu = props => {
  const shadow = 'hsla(218, 50%, 10%, 0.1)';
  return (
    <div
      css={{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 4,
        boxShadow: `0 0 0 1px ${shadow}, 0 4px 11px ${shadow}`,
        marginTop: 8,
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 2,
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
const Blanket = props => (
  <div
    css={{
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      position: 'fixed',
      zIndex: 1,
    }}
    {...props}
  />
);
const Dropdown = ({ children, isOpen, target, onClose }) => (
  <div css={{ position: 'relative' }}>
    {target}
    {isOpen ? <Menu>{children}</Menu> : null}
    {isOpen ? <Blanket onClick={onClose} /> : null}
  </div>
);
const Svg = p => (
  <svg
    width="24"
    height="24"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    focusable="false"
    role="presentation"
    {...p}
  />
);
const DropdownIndicator = () => (
  <div css={{ color: colors.neutral20, height: 24, width: 32 }}>
    <Svg>
      <path
        d="M16.436 15.085l3.94 4.01a1 1 0 0 1-1.425 1.402l-3.938-4.006a7.5 7.5 0 1 1 1.423-1.406zM10.5 16a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11z"
        fill="currentColor"
        fillRule="evenodd"
      />
    </Svg>
  </div>
);
const ChevronDown = () => (
  <Svg style={{ marginRight: -6 }}>
    <path
      d="M8.292 10.293a1.009 1.009 0 0 0 0 1.419l2.939 2.965c.218.215.5.322.779.322s.556-.107.769-.322l2.93-2.955a1.01 1.01 0 0 0 0-1.419.987.987 0 0 0-1.406 0l-2.298 2.317-2.307-2.327a.99.99 0 0 0-1.406 0z"
      fill="currentColor"
      fillRule="evenodd"
    />
  </Svg>
```

Answer (score -2):

Has been resolved in react-select V2. Refer https://react-select.com/home